# Resetting a value before you return

Tags: java, return

I have got a simple sumOf method which calculates sum of geometric series:

```
public int sumOf(int terms) {
for(int i = 0; i < terms; i++){
sum += getNextTerm();
}
int b = sum;
sum = 0;
return b;
}
```

The summation works fine, but as you can see I am trying to reset the sum variable to zero before I return, but in quite a stupid way. I am making a new int and storing the sum in there, then resetting.

Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Yes. make `sum` a local variable. I really can't see the point of your decision to use an instance variable here.

Comment: Where are the `sum` variable defined in your code?

Comment: BTW to answer your literal question: you could have written `try { return sum; } finally { sum = 0; }`

Comment: It's a global variable, and that is a good point, should of just stored it locally. So it resets every time the method gets called. A bit of a stupid question, but thanks.

Comment: Besides not using a field (but a local variable) and using finally, you can also reset the sum at the beginning of the loop. You did not describe what the sematic is so we can hardly tell you anything better. If you really need a reset+return like you shown there is nothing wrong with the way you did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use a local variable.

```
public int sumOf(int terms) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < terms; i++){
        sum += getNextTerm();
    }
    return sum;
}
```

There's little point in using a field in this case, if the method doesn't change it at all.

Answer (score 2):

You might use `resetSum()` method, which resets your variable `sum`, like this:

```
private void resetSum() {
        this.sum = 0;
}
```

And next, you might use `try-finally` statement, like this:

```
public int sumOf(int terms) {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < terms; i++) {
            sum += getNextTerm();
        }
        return sum;
    } finally {
        resetSum();
    }
}
```

Comment: How does using a method make this approach any better?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare `sum` as a local variable to eliminate the need for resetting it. You can also return `sum` directly without using another intermediary variable `b`.

```
public int sumOf(int terms) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < terms; i++){
        sum += getNextTerm();
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sum a local variable and then you don't need to reset it.

```
public int sumOf(int terms) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < terms; i++){
        sum += getNextTerm();
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a local variable to keep the sum.

```
public int sumOf(int terms) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < terms; i++) {
    sum += getNextTerm();
  }
  return sum;
}
```

BTW if you happen to be using Java 8, you can use an FP idiom instead.

```
public int sumOf(int terms) {
  return IntStream.generate(this::getNextTerm)
                  .limit(terms)
                  .sum();
}
```